# How to read a file of 1 GB and sort the data within the file

Tags: java

Someone asked me this question in an interview like if I have a file which is 1 GB of size which has number in random order, I want to sort the numbers in the file. My machine doesn’t have this much space to read 1 GB file in one go. How can I read the file and sort the data and store it back to file again in sorted format.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting